# implement something on all OnClickListener in Application (Any Middleware)

Tags: android, performance

I have 100 of buttons in my application and i want to add sound on
 all button clicks what should i do for this?
I donot want to do add sound on all clicks suggest(Any middleware)

```
  ArriveBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {

 // mis-clicking prevention or repid click, using threshold of 1000 ms
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000){
            return;
        }
        mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

      Popup(HomeActivity.this);
    });
```

**i use 100 of these clicks and want to play same sound on all these clicks**

Comment: implement  public @OnClick({R.id.arriveBth}) public void onClick(View view){} then use view.getId() to get id in the above care view.getId() will return arriveBth   if you want to add same code to all on click just  ignore view.getId()

Comment: yes i want any middleware that detect any click in my application and play the sound

Comment: better create custom button extending button and on override the onTouch to your default sound and apply to all xml.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do is to make custom Button class like this

```
public class CustomButtonForSound extends Button {

public interface CustomButtonOnClick {
    void onCustomClick(View v);
}

public CustomButtonForSound(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomButtonForSound(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomButtonForSound(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public void setOnCustomClickListener(final CustomButtonOnClick customButtonOnClick) {

    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //play sound code
            customButtonOnClick.onCustomClick(v);
        }
    });
}
}
```

and use like this in your main class

```
customButtonForSound.setOnCustomClickListener(new CustomButtonForSound.CustomButtonOnClick() {
        @Override
        public void onCustomClick(View v) {
             // your normal onClick code
        }
    });
```

Comment: if you want to make a custom `Button` then simply override `View#performClick` method

Comment: yes its good
but i want all working in MainActivity and play sound only in CustomButtonForSound when user click
thanks
@Omer

Comment: @AhmadTahir this is exactly i m doing

Comment: i make class as it is
but in main class i pass the VIEW in this listner and check the button with Id in CustomButtonForSound ?

customButtonForSound.setOnCustomClickListener not accept (ArriveBtn.setOnCustomClickListener)

Comment: driverArrivedBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {


            customButtonForSound.setOnCustomClickListener(new CustomButtonForSound.CustomButtonOnClick() {
                @Override
                public void onCustomClick(View v) {

                    arrivedConfirmationPopup(HomeActivity.this);                }
            });
        });

Comment: @Omer may i do this

Comment: @AhmadTahir you dont need any `setOnCustomClickListener`, just override `View#performClick` method

Comment: you are doing it wrong..you need to use CustomButtonForSound button instead of normal Button in your xml as well

Comment: and in `MainActivity.java` you need to to `CustomButtonForSound customButtonForSound = (CustomButtonForSound)findViewById(R.id.use_your_id);
        customButtonForSound.setOnCustomClickListener(new CustomButtonForSound.CustomButtonOnClick() {
            @Override
            public void onCustomClick(View v) {
//your normal onClick code
            }
        });`

Comment: @Omer you dont need it: no need for any `setOnCustomClickListener` method, just override `performClick`, thats all

Comment: @pskink but i have 100's of buttons its very difficult to add on all buttons

Comment: @AhmadTahir what is difficult? just create one custom `Button` class and override its `performClick` method

Comment: `class MyButton extends Button { @Override boolean performClick () { your code here; return super.performClick(); } ...`

Comment: @pskink good
Where i should do
ArriveBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {

 // mis-clicking prevention or repid click, using threshold of 1000 ms
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000){
            return;
        }
        mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

      Popup(HomeActivity.this);
    });

Comment: @pskink i want to implement my logic in MainActivity and play sound ony in Button Class

Comment: @pskink i do this
  driverArrivedBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            customButtonForSound.performClick();
// mis-clicking prevention or repid click, using threshold of 1000 ms
            if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000){
                return;
            }
            mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

            arrivedConfirmationPopup(HomeActivity.this);
        });

Comment: and? whats the problem? if you need custom code to be called just use normal `View#setOnClickListener` method

Comment: @pskink brother its not better i make function and call on every button click
both are taken same time i want middleware way to handle this?

Comment: @ pskink i use View#setOnClickListener and then             customButtonForSound.performClick();

Comment: @pskink
driverArrivedBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            customButtonForSound.performClick();
// mis-clicking prevention or repid click, using threshold of 1000 ms
            if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000){
                return;
            }
            mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

            arrivedConfirmationPopup(HomeActivity.this);
        });